For continuous surjective $f:R^n\times R^n\to R^n$. Does $\exists g:R^n\times R^n\to R^n$ right-inverse in the second argument, continuous in first?
Assume $f:R^n\times R^n\to R^n$ is continuous, and that for each $x$, $h(y)=f(x,y)$ is surjective. Does there exist a $g:R^n\times R^n\to R^n$ that is a "right-inverse in the second argument", and continuous in first? It doesn't have to be continuous in the second argument.
That is, we want that for all $x,y$, we have $f(x,g(x,y))=y$, and that for all $y$ we have that $h(x)=g(x,y)$ is a continuous function. If not in general, what sufficient conditions could we make so that it holds?
